# Change CSV delimiter when using mgconsole?

Tags: memgraphdb

I can see that comma (`,`) is the default delimiter. For one specific scenario I need to use `;` but I don't want to change CSV file manually. How can I change CSV delimiter when using `mgconsole`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `mgconsole` flag called `-csv_delimiter`. The type of this flag is `string`, and the default value is `","`. Just define the value to the one that fits your needs.